# Use linux machine audio mic input as line in

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

Is it possible to transfer (stream, reroute) sound from a Windows PC output to Linux audio input using a Jack to Jack cable?

[image]

Comment: Yes of course !

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible.

In that case, you would treat the audio-in as a microphone.  Pulse-audio has tools like `pavucontrol` which let you manage your audio inputs, and even let you permanently redirect your sources to sinks if you want a hot-mic type of system.

However, there is quality loss when you convert the other machine's sound to analog, over the wire, then back to digital.  You may be more satisfied with an digital sound protocol like a Dante audio-over-ethernet.

Comment: "you would treat the audio-in as a microphone" Not exactly since a microphone would need some extra amplifier when the sound output of the PC is already amplified. This well lead to another cause of loss of quality since standard PC audio amplifiers are of poor quality.

Comment: The above comment leading to the advice to push input levels to maximum (these are attenuators only => no risk of distortion) and keep PC sound output volume the lowest possible since distortion increases with volume.

Comment: @Stewart 
How do I redirect your sources to sinks (my main output) in pavucontrol 
I can see the different inputs, outputs but not exactly where to redirect